# How to move data from partitioned table to another partitioned table

Tags: oracle, partitioning, database-administration, oracle19c

I have two monthly interval partitioned tables table1 and table2. Table1 is history table which holds historic data and table2 holds latest/live 6 months data. Every month I need to add or move the oldest partition from table2 to the history table table1.

Comment: Can't you just exchange the partitions? Oracle cannot directly exchange between two partitioned tables, but with an intermediate step Partition (table1) > table > Partition (table2) that should be no problem ...

Comment: Do you really need this? If queries use appropriate filtering, then old data will not be accessed without moving it to another table

Comment: @astentx - whether or not to remove a partition from a table most often is more of data maintenance than a performance question. You are correct, with appropriate filtering you should not have to worry about the data and be able to rely on either static or dynamic pruning.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with no movement of data, just dictionary operations as Hermann has suggested.

T1 is my current 6 months, and T2 is history

```
    SQL> create table t1
      2  partition by range (x)
      3  interval ( numtoyminterval(1,'MONTH') )
      4  ( partition p1 values less than ( date '2021-01-01') )
      5  as
      6    select date '2021-01-01'+rownum x,
      7           rownum y
      8    from dual
      9    connect by level <= 180;
    
    Table created.
    
    SQL>
    SQL> create table t2
      2  partition by range (x)
      3  interval ( numtoyminterval(1,'MONTH') )
      4  ( partition p1 values less than ( date '2015-01-01') )
      5  as
      6    select date '2021-01-01'-rownum x,
      7           rownum y
      8    from dual
      9    connect by level <= 1000;
    
    Table created.
    
    SQL>
    SQL> select partition_name, high_value
      2  from   user_tab_partitions
      3  where  table_name = 'T1';
    
    PARTITION_NAME                 HIGH_VALUE
    ------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    P1                             TO_DATE(' 2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22038                     TO_DATE(' 2021-02-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22039                     TO_DATE(' 2021-03-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22040                     TO_DATE(' 2021-04-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22041                     TO_DATE(' 2021-05-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22042                     TO_DATE(' 2021-06-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22043                     TO_DATE(' 2021-07-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    
    7 rows selected.
    
    SQL>
    SQL> select partition_name, high_value
      2  from   user_tab_partitions
      3  where  table_name = 'T2';
    
    PARTITION_NAME                 HIGH_VALUE
    ------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    P1                             TO_DATE(' 2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22044                     TO_DATE(' 2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22045                     TO_DATE(' 2020-12-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22046                     TO_DATE(' 2020-11-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22047                     TO_DATE(' 2020-10-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22048                     TO_DATE(' 2020-09-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22049                     TO_DATE(' 2020-08-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22050                     TO_DATE(' 2020-07-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22051                     TO_DATE(' 2020-06-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22052                     TO_DATE(' 2020-05-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22053                     TO_DATE(' 2020-04-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22054                     TO_DATE(' 2020-03-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22055                     TO_DATE(' 2020-02-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22056                     TO_DATE(' 2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22057                     TO_DATE(' 2019-12-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22058                     TO_DATE(' 2019-11-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22059                     TO_DATE(' 2019-10-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22060                     TO_DATE(' 2019-09-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22061                     TO_DATE(' 2019-08-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22062                     TO_DATE(' 2019-07-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22063                     TO_DATE(' 2019-06-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22064                     TO_DATE(' 2019-05-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22065                     TO_DATE(' 2019-04-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22066                     TO_DATE(' 2019-03-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22067                     TO_DATE(' 2019-02-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22068                     TO_DATE(' 2019-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22069                     TO_DATE(' 2018-12-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22070                     TO_DATE(' 2018-11-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22071                     TO_DATE(' 2018-10-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22072                     TO_DATE(' 2018-09-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22073                     TO_DATE(' 2018-08-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22074                     TO_DATE(' 2018-07-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22075                     TO_DATE(' 2018-06-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22076                     TO_DATE(' 2018-05-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    
    34 rows selected.
```

To do a table exchange, you need to create a template table first, ie, you need something to exchange *with*

```
    SQL>
    SQL> create table exc
      2  for exchange with table t1;
    
    Table created.
```

Now I take the partition I want to remove from T1, and exchange it with EXC

```
    SQL>
    SQL> alter table t1 exchange partition for ( date '2021-01-15' ) with table exc;
    
    Table altered.
```

Now I want to exchange it "into" T2, but I need a partition in T2 into which I can do the exchange.  That partition does not exist yet, because it doesn't contain any of the 6 months in the current data.  Thus we need to create an empty one.  A simple trick to do that is the lock the non-existent partition, which will have the effect of creating one.

```
    SQL>
    SQL> lock table t2 partition for ( date '2021-01-15' ) in exclusive mode;
    
    Table(s) Locked.
    
    SQL>
    SQL> select partition_name, high_value
      2  from   user_tab_partitions
      3  where  table_name = 'T2';
    
    PARTITION_NAME                 HIGH_VALUE
    ------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    P1                             TO_DATE(' 2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22044                     TO_DATE(' 2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22045                     TO_DATE(' 2020-12-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22046                     TO_DATE(' 2020-11-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22047                     TO_DATE(' 2020-10-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22048                     TO_DATE(' 2020-09-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22049                     TO_DATE(' 2020-08-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22050                     TO_DATE(' 2020-07-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22051                     TO_DATE(' 2020-06-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22052                     TO_DATE(' 2020-05-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22053                     TO_DATE(' 2020-04-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22054                     TO_DATE(' 2020-03-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22055                     TO_DATE(' 2020-02-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22056                     TO_DATE(' 2020-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22057                     TO_DATE(' 2019-12-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22058                     TO_DATE(' 2019-11-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22059                     TO_DATE(' 2019-10-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22060                     TO_DATE(' 2019-09-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22061                     TO_DATE(' 2019-08-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22062                     TO_DATE(' 2019-07-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22063                     TO_DATE(' 2019-06-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22064                     TO_DATE(' 2019-05-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22065                     TO_DATE(' 2019-04-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22066                     TO_DATE(' 2019-03-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22067                     TO_DATE(' 2019-02-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22068                     TO_DATE(' 2019-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22069                     TO_DATE(' 2018-12-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22070                     TO_DATE(' 2018-11-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22071                     TO_DATE(' 2018-10-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22072                     TO_DATE(' 2018-09-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22073                     TO_DATE(' 2018-08-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22074                     TO_DATE(' 2018-07-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22075                     TO_DATE(' 2018-06-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22076                     TO_DATE(' 2018-05-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    SYS_P22077                     TO_DATE(' 2021-02-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 
    
    35 rows selected.
```

Notice that we gained a new partition (which is empty). Now I exchange the EXC table (which has 1 month of data) with the empty partition.

```
SQL>
SQL> alter table t2 exchange partition for ( date '2021-01-15' ) with table exc;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

and we are done.  Notice that we never needed to reference any of the interval partitions by name, we just used the FOR option in order to avoid that.

Comment: great tip and thanks for sharing. For clarity, should there be an unlock and can it be done immediately after the lock?

Comment: Do really think the LOCK is needed?

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Connor McDonald. I am getting the below error for final alter statement  when I use “create table for exchange with” for creating the temporarily table. 
But when I create the temp table with the same statement of t1 and t2 table removing the partition clause. It works. 

ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in alter table exchange partition.

Comment: I tried with create table temp as select * from t1, this did not work too. 
How can I solve this other then creating the create table manually?

Comment: Are you doing "create for exchange" because that will copy any hidden attributes as well.  And of course, the two partitioned tables (T1 and T2) need to have identical column structures.  You can check USER_TAB_COLS for each

Comment: @Conner McDonald. Thanks for the reply.  Yes I am doing create for exchange. And the error was because of primary key on both T1 and T2. So it worked after creating the primary key on temp table.    
create table exc for exchange with table t1;  alter table exc add primary key (ID);

Comment: But I couldn’t figure out how to handle below error for the same scenario.    
ORA-14098: Index mismatch for tables in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION

Comment: Because you are doing an exchange, everything about the EXC table and the partition must be the same (indexes, constraints etc).  Also check the docs for the "excluding" clause which gives a little leeway in this area

Comment: @Connor McDonald indexes becoming unusable. I tried including indexes option with exchange partition. 

Cretate index I1 on T1(column2) local;                     Create index I2 on T2(column2) local; 
Create index I3 on exc(column2); 
ORA-14098: index mismatch for tables in alter table exchange partition.  For every non partitioned index for the non partitioned table, there has to be an identical index on the partitioned table. Is there anything I can do other then rebuilding the indexes?

Comment: Probably help a lot more if you updated the original question with the DDL for all objects concerned, so we eliminate guesswork